# Php test empty string

Tags: php, string

I have a bit of php code that I'm not understanding why it is acting as it is.  I have a variable called contactId that I want to test to see if it is empty.  However even if it is empty it evaluates to true.  Code is below.  Thanks in advance.

```
print "*".$contactId."*<br/>";
if($contactId != '')
{
    //queryContact($contactId);
    print "Contact Present<br/>";
}
```

result returned to screen is:

> **
>
> Contact Present

Comment: I think it's because the variable is NULL if it's not defined

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to see exactly what your string is, simply use `var_dump()`, like this, for instance:

```
var_dump($contactId)
```

instead of

```
print "*".$contactId."*<br/>";
```

Comment: The snippet works fine for me via php cli, would be interesting whats exactly inside the variable.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!  var_dump showed me what I actually had in the variable.  Turns out that I had an xml tag in there that wouldn't print because it was in <> but var_dump showed it.  The above code works now!

Comment: Cool! Now I guess you won't use the `"*" . $var . "*"` method again ;)

Comment: How does this response answer the OP's question?

Comment: @Kingsolmn: Let's sum up the question : "I want to test to see if it is empty". How does my response not answer this question?

Comment: @greg0ire Sorry I had too long of a day yesterday. Originally I thought the OP was asking how to test programmatically for an empty string, after some sleep I see the question is simpler. My humble apologies good sir.

Comment: @Kingsolmn: apologies accepted, I'm glad to see some people are brave enough to admit when they're wrong. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things you can try:

```
if (!empty($contactId)) {
    // I have a contact Id
}

// Or

if (strlen($contactId) > 0) {
    // I have a contact id
}
```

In my experience I have often used the latter of the two solutions because there have been instances where I would expect a variable to have the value of 0, which is valid in some contexts. For example, if I have a drink search site and want to indicate if an ingredient is non-alcoholic I would assign it a value of 0 (i.e. IngredientId = 7, Alcoholic = 0).

Answer (score 1):

Do it with `if (isset($contactId)) {}`.

Comment: then it means $contacId isnt set yet. just set it before using

Comment: if you got '' <- empty string, then isset() return true!

Comment: @jcmitch : if this evaluates to `false`, `$contactId` is not set so you should get a notice telling you so. Make sure your php setting `display_errors` is set to 1, and that `error_reporting` is set to -1

Answer (score 0):

You likely want:

```
if (strlen($contactId))
```

You'll want to learn the difference between `''` and `null`, and between `==` and `===`. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

and here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

Comment: not really good, cuz if you haven't yet got any value into $contactId, - you'll get notice

Answer (score 0):

In future, use `if(!empty($str)) { echo "string is not empty"}`.

Comment: OP, FYI, This will exclude the possibly legitimate `$contactId="0";`.

Comment: Yes. empty will return true for:
    `"" (an empty string)`,
    `0 (0 as an integer)`,
    `0.0 (0 as a float)`,
    `"0" (0 as a string)`,
    `NULL`,
    `FALSE`,
    `array() (an empty array)`,
    `var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)`,

for your case - `$contactId`, if it is numeric, then just check it like `is_numeric`